# Solve an arithmetic string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

suppose I have the following code:

```
    var str = "4*(3)^2/1"
```

Is the simplest solution just to make a stack of the operators and solve with postfix notation? Or is there a really basic solution I'm missing.

Additionally how can I adapt if I'm using log, ln, sin, cos, and tan?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to respond to my own question, but the easiest solution is using [math.js](http://mathjs.org/)

```
    var ans = math.eval(str);
```

Comment: Answers should contain a solution. This is merely a suggestion to use a library to solve a problem. Maybe show how to use the library instead of just linking to it.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest yet a bit dangerous so you may have to validate (clean) an expression before evaluating is using eval (for exponent-operator `^`, replace it with the exponent-operator in JavaScript `**`):

```js
var str="4*(3)^2/1".replace(/\^/g,'**');
console.log(eval(str));
```

And for special functions such as `sin`, `cos`, `exp` and so on, create a function of your own using the corresponding predefined function in JavaScript:

```js
var str="4*(3)^2/1+(exp(5)*cos(14)^(1/sin(13)))^2".replace(/\^/g,'**');
function sin(x) { return Math.sin(x) }
function cos(x) { return Math.cos(x) }
// so on
function exp(x) { return Math.exp(x) }
console.log(eval(str));
```

Comment: What about `^`?

Comment: @ringø I edited the answer, you basically replace the `^` with `**` since the latter does exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `postfix` notation. You can use `eval` method.

```js
var str = "4*(3)^2/1";
console.log(str);
console.log(eval(str));
```

Also, another solution is using [javascript-expression-evaluator](https://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/) which allows you to do stuff like:

```
Parser.evaluate("2 ^ x", { x: 4 });
```

Comment: be very cautious with what you pass as paramter. If the expression is from the clent, be sure to sanitize it properly.

Comment: OP probably sees `^2` as square, not `XOR 2`

Comment: should I use Math.pow() instead then?